# How can I run gradle startscript created using installDist task from a batch file in windows OS?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, gradle

I have Executed the gradle installDist task for my project. After that two start scripts were created one for running in unix like system and another for windows.

I am able to successfully execute the script created for unix systems. But when I tried to run the windows .bat file in my windows system. It is giving below error in command line.

Even if I am trying to run the batch file directly from cmd. It is giving the below error

**The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.**

Comment: Post the generated script

Comment: Actually it has project related informations. Do you want me to check something in the generated batch file which could give the following error "The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is incorrect."

PS: I am running batch file by dragging it in cmd and then hitting enter.

Comment: Two usual causes of such behavior are a path too long, or some recursive junction.